# OWIN cookie authentication OnValidateIdentity should be called on every request?

Tags: vb.net, cookies, asp.net-identity, owin

Perhaps I am misunderstanding how this works, but I thought the `OnValidateIdentity` would be called on every HTTP request to the server. I see it get hit on initial login (a bunch of times, so it looks like it is every HTTP request on initially), but then it doesn't seem to get called again. I let my app sit there until it should be expired, but it never gets hit again on subsequent requests to the server, until I logout and login again.

I have set my expiry very low and turned off sliding expiration to see if I could get it to fail, but to no avail.

Should I not see the `OnValidateIdentity` get called on every HTTP request? Ultimately, I really just want a cookie expiry to result in a logout. I assumed I had to check the expiry on each request in the `OnValidateIdentity`, but if this is not the way to do it please let me know!

Am I misunderstanding how this work, or how I should be using cookie expiries to force a logout?

Here is my basic setup:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With
        {
            .AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            .AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            .ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0),
            .SlidingExpiration = False,
            .Provider = New CookieAuthenticationProvider() With
                        {
                            .OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity(Of ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, Integer)(
                                validateInterval:=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0),
                                regenerateIdentityCallback:=Async Function(manager, user)
                                                                Return Await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)
                                                            End Function,
                                getUserIdCallback:=Function(id) id.GetUserId(Of Integer)())
                        },
            .LoginPath = New PathString("/Account/Login")
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late...

To use cookie Expiry, that's delegated to the browser.  If a cookie expires, then the browser wouldn't send it.

OnValidateIdentity is called on every request.  If you want to debug it, pull it out into a new method and debug from that method instead.

However, the identity itself is only validated against the database when the validationInterval is passed.